# AJAX+Rails Click Handler Not Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a JS file that is downloaded via an AJAX request from my server. All the code fires, except the click handler appears to not be binding.

```
$("#deal_<%= escape_javascript @deal.id.to_s %>").fadeOut("slow", function(){
   var div = $("<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'edit_deal', locals: {deal: @deal} %>").hide();
   div.closest('.save_deal_link').click(function(event) {
        alert("hi!"); // THIS ALERT DOES NOT FIRE ON CLICKING THE LINK
        event.preventDefault();
        // Prevent link from following its href
    });
   $("#deal_<%= escape_javascript @deal.id.to_s %>").replaceWith(div);
   div.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Is binding a click handler disallowed when used through AJAX or is it getting wiped when the relevant partial is rendered onto the page?

Comment: Is the link inside the new div (the one instantiated with `var div`)?

Comment: @ryan0319 yep, it is.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/closest/ - the `.closest()` traverses up through itself, then parents... I think you want `.first()` or `.find(.save...').eq(0)`

Comment: Thanks! @ryan0319 I was reading through rails docs on how it handles this. Wrong docs XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this behavior I needed to do this:

```
div.children('.save_deal_link').first().click(function(event) {
    alert("hi!");
    event.preventDefault();
    // Prevent link from following its href
});
```